# @grid.GetHtml method not found in asp.net MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a Nested WebGrid with Expand/Collapse in ASP.NET MVC4, but it gives me an error  **Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2 System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.ObjectToDictionary(System.Object)'.**, i really don't know how to resolve this error. please help.

**My View Model**

```
public class PackagesVM
{
    public Packages package { get; set; }
    public List<Lot> packLots { get; set; }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetPackagesLot()
    {
        List<PackagesVM> packagesLots = new List<PackagesVM>();

        // here MyDatabaseEntities is our data context
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            var pack = db.Packages1.OrderByDescending(a => a.id);
            foreach (var i in pack)
            {
                var lot = db.Lots.Where(a => a.pack_id==i.id).ToList();
                packagesLots.Add(new PackagesVM { package = i, packLots = lot });
            }
        }
        return View(packagesLots);
    }
```

**My View**

```
<div id="main" style="padding:25px; background-color:white;">
@grid.GetHtml(
htmlAttributes: new {id="gridT", width="700px" },
columns:grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("package.Id","Pack ID"),
        grid.Column("package.Name","Package Name"),
        grid.Column("package.Province_id","Province"),
        grid.Column(header:"Create at",format:(item)=> string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",item.package.created_at)),

        grid.Column(format:(item)=>{
            WebGrid subGrid = new WebGrid(source: item.packLots);
            return subGrid.GetHtml(
                htmlAttributes: new { id="subT" },
                columns:subGrid.Columns(
                        subGrid.Column("id","Id"),
                        subGrid.Column("lot_number", "Lot Number"),
                        subGrid.Column("pack_id", "Package ID"),
                        subGrid.Column("contracted_amount", "Amount")
                    )                    
                );
        })
    )
)
```

**My Script**

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var size = $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").size(); // get total column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").last().remove(); // remove last column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr").prepend("<th></th>"); // add one column at first for collapsible column
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).prepend(
                    $("<td></td>")
                    .addClass("expand")
                    .addClass("hoverEff")
                    .attr('title',"click for show/hide")
                );

            //Now get sub table from last column and add this to the next new added row
            var table = $("table", this).parent().html();
            //add new row with this subtable
            $(this).after("<tr><td></td><td style='padding:5px; margin:0px;' colspan='" + (size - 1) + "'>" + table + "</td></tr>");
            $("table", this).parent().remove();
            // ADD CLICK EVENT FOR MAKE COLLAPSIBLE
            $(".hoverEff", this).live("click", function () {
                $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            });
        });

        //by default make all subgrid in collapse mode
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr td.expand").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Error**
}[image]

Comment: Please go to this sample : http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3139/webgrid-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a grid like following code line in the **BeginForm** block at your view file.

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model.PackagesVM, canSort: false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please also Add this nuget Package AD.System.Web.Helpers.dll

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add sample code with comments - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.