# collaps and uncollaps is not working in my script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have used Master Nested Grid View in my project, it can list all Lots based on its Packages, but Collapse/UnCollapses is not working in my script

the error is **.live is not a function** which is not supported in my Jquery version and i have changed it into .On but still its not working, please check my script and help me whats wrong??.

**Scripts**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var size = $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").size(); // get total column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr >th").last().remove(); // remove last column
        $("#main #gridT > thead > tr").prepend("<th></th>"); // add one column at first for collapsible column
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).prepend(
                    $("<td></td>")
                    .addClass("expand")
                    .addClass("hoverEff")
                    .attr('title',"click for show/hide")
                );

            //Now get sub table from last column and add this to the next new added row
            var table = $("table", this).parent().html();
            //add new row with this subtable
            $(this).after("<tr><td></td><td style='padding:5px; margin:0px;' colspan='" + (size - 1) + "'>" + table + "</td></tr>");
            $("table", this).parent().remove();
            // ADD CLICK EVENT FOR MAKE COLLAPSIBLE
            **$(".hoverEff", this).live("click", function () {**
                $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
                $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            });
        });

        //by default make all subgrid in collapse mode
        $("#main #gridT > tbody > tr td.expand").each(function (i, el) {
            $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
            $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
        });

    });
</script>
```

**The result is**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.live` is deprecated and removed in jquery version 1.9 and further. use `.on` instead:

```
$("#gridT").on("click",'.hoverEff',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expand collapse");
        $(this).parent().closest("tr").next().slideToggle(100);
});
```

Comment: i changed it accordingly, but now the problems is that its un collapsed and still on-click event is not working to collapse it again.

Comment: i just changed your code on my above working snippet. do you need to add all working snippet including controller,model and view??

Comment: my complete code is :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734279/grid-gethtml-method-not-found-in-asp-net-mvc-view?noredirect=1#comment68695525_40734279

Comment: Nope. just html and relevant js.

Comment: please refer to View and Script part of my previews post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734279/grid-gethtml-method-not-found-in-asp-net-mvc-view?noredirect=1#comment68695525_40734279

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i found the solution, i just change the default class for collapse and expand, not its working correctly.

Comment: Ok. Dont forget to accept the answer if it helped :)